# Return statements for all functions

Tags: coding-style, return

How common is it for coding style guidelines to include a requirement that all functions include at least one return statement (even functions which return void)?

To avoid being subjective or argumentative, I'd like answers which can name specific companies or open-source projects which have this requirement. If you haven't ever come across this coding style guideline, or you have a resource (book, online article) which discusses it, that would be useful as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Include at least 1 return statement would be better verbage.

Comment: @Nissan: Seriously? I can't see the point of writing a completely redundant line of code as the last line in a function.

Comment: @Troubadour  While I don't disagree that it's redudant for void scenarios, at the same time there are those of us using languages like C# which allow for labels http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2(VS.71).aspx which usually are kicked after a return;  BTW I was not saying it's a must to do this, I was saying that if you are going to require this make sure the verbage indicates the fact that there can be n returns in a code block.

Comment: Nissan made his first comment when my original wording had said "all functions include a return statement". I interpreted his comment as meaning that if that is a requirement that it is better to word it as "all functions include at least one return statement".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I've never seen such a guideline at either of the (C++) companies I've worked for.

My first company did have a guideline about minimising the number of points of return. For functions returning void that would implicitly imply that they preferred there to be no return statements in the function I suppose.

Comment: Agreed, I've never heard the requirement for return statements in void functions. The idea strikes me as dogmatic.